# Default visible slide in jquery menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

I have this code below and it works great for loading content in a div from a leftnav menu, I just need the page to display the "first" selection in the content box when the user first navigates to the page, is it as simple as including the default content into the Div in html, and then loading on top of it after? Does this make sense to anyone?

```
<div id="pressInfo"></div>


var urls = [
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/press-info.inc #current_news',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/press-info.inc #mission_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/press-info.inc #press_releases',  
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/press-info.inc #staff_bios',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/press-info.inc #testimonials_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/press-info.inc #awards_',
 ];
$(function() {
    $.each(urls, function(i, url) {
    var index = i+1;
        $("li.press_"+index+" a").bind('click', function(e){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('current-item')) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $('#press li a').addClass('current-item').not(this).removeClass('current-item');
            $('#pressInfo').fadeOut(250, function() {
                $(this).hide().load(url, function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(250);
                });
            }); 
        }
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: `"is it as simple as including the default content into the Div in html, and then loading on top of it after?"`  It should be, yes.

Comment: Here is a basic tabbed content example I put together that may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/DWmfX/

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do it.  You can, as you suggest, just build the content for the first item into the HTML directly.  The alternative is to trigger the click event for this first item in document ready.

```
$(function() {
    $('#press li:first a').trigger('click');
});
```